# How to format a document in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I noticed other questions about Notepad++ on this site, so I figured this was the appropriate place to ask. Mods, if this isn't the right place, please relocate.

How do you format your document in Notepad++? I'm looking for something similar to Visual Studio's Edit > Advanced > Format Document

I have a large xml document that is all on one line, I would like it to be formatted with the proper indents/whitespace and only one element per line.

Edit: Using the stock version 5.9.5 with no plug ins.

Comment: Same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961217/how-to-format-xml-in-notepad) ?

Comment: You could use sed or vi to do this pretty quickly, but not automatically.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do it with the stock setup, not using plug ins. My version of Notepad++ does not have the xml plugin or the pretty print plugin.

Comment: Then you should include the exact version you are using

Comment: Downloaded the minimalist version and I couldn't find that functionality but I don't use Notepad++. The mentioned plugins seems to be available for your version, any reason you can't use those?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to do it without plug ins. Why take an extra step if you don't need to. But, if there isn't a way to do it without plugins, then I guess I will just go ahead and download them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Download XML Tools plugin from NotePad++->Plugins->XML Tools.. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to format your XML document..

Answer (score 6):

+1 for XML Tools.

You can download the plugin from the Plugin Manager and then use ":

1. Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager
2. Select XML Tools and install
3. Plugins > XML Tools > Pretty Print (XML only - with line breaks).

This corresponds to the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

If this does not work with your version of Notepad++ (damn, you have an old old one!), you can download the plugin and install it yourself:

1. Go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/
2. Put the dll file in /plugins
3. Restart Notepad++ and that's it