# Notepad++ XML Display on seperate lines like Internet Explorer Display Of XML

Tags: xml, notepad++

How do I get Notepad++ to display my XML on different lines like Internet Explorer (please note I can't change the XML).

Screenshot of XML displayed in Internet Explorer
[image]
Screenshot of XML displayed in Notepad++
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try Plugins -> XML Tools -> Pretty Print (libXML) or (XML only - with line breaks Ctrl+Alt+Shift+B)

In my experience, libXML gives nice output but only if the file is 100% correctly formed.

You may need to install XML Tools (Plugins | Plugin Manager), if it isn't already installed.

Credit: [How to format XML in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961217/how-to-format-xml-in-notepad?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer uses an XSLT (its an embedded resource in one the the IE dlls<sup>1</sup>) to transform the XML into HTML with styling and some JavaScript (allowing elements to be expanded/collapsed).

You'll need to do something similar. A no-op XSLT (input and output XML are the same except for non-significant whitespace) with `<xsl:output … indent="yes" />` would at least get something readable.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've forgotten which one, but reading it was instructive.

Comment: can you actually do this within Notepad++?

Comment: No idea: my focus on explaining how IE does it and thus the core of an approach. XSLT authoring and integration when loading applicable target files on load is left as an exercise :-).