# How to make pretty print in programmer's notepad

Tags: python, xml, pretty-print, programmers-notepad

In programmer's notepad is my xml code in one line. How can I make pretty print?
I made code with python.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961217/how-to-format-xml-in-notepad

Comment: check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749796/pretty-printing-xml-in-python

Comment: @MortezaIpo That is Notepad++, not Programmer's Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

For Programmer's Notepad you can use [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to accomplish this. To set this up, follow the directions as [explained here in the Programmer's Notepad guide](http://pnotepad.org/docs/xml_formatting/).

Comment: isn't tidy for python 2.1 to 2.5?

Comment: @user3639326 No, you add it to Programmer's Notepad, not Python itself.