# Configure proxy settings in Notepad++ via Plugin Manager

Tags: windows, proxy, notepad++

I would like to configure proxy settings in Notepad++ to allow downloads from the internet via a proxy. After searching how to do that from the net I understand that I need to do that in the Plugin Manager, via the Settings button. When I go to Plugins>Plugin Manager>Show Plugin Manager>Settings I get the dialog box below which does not give me any option for indicating the proxy settings. How do I get to the point that I need to indicate the proxy settings?

[image]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Open cmd and type:

```
cd /d C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\updater
gup -options
```

A dialog comes up to set the proxy settings.

Comment: I needed to run `cmd.exe` as administrator to save that settings successfully.

Comment: I have Notepad++ v6.9.2 and there is no gup.exe inside the "updater" folder. There is only a gpup.exe, and when I run "gpup - options" I get this error popup: "Invalid parameters passed to the plugin updater (GPUP). Usage: gpup.exe -w <window name> -e <exe name> [-a <actions file>". Does anyone know how to change the proxy settings in Notepad++ v6.9.2 ?

Comment: The update helper GPU.exe is only bundled with the Installer version. Do you use a portable version or the minimalist version?

Comment: A note: the settings will be stored in this XML file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\updater\gupOptions.xml"

Comment: @xs6 where can I put username and password for proxy ?

Got the solution : https://superuser.com/a/696538/467458

Comment: For 64-bit version of NPP this will be `cd /d C:\Program Files\Notepad++\updater`

Answer (score 23):

with version 7.6.6 (april 2019) (probably onwards), you can run notepad++ as admin, use menu '?' > Set Updater Proxy... close notepad++ and open it again as standard user.

Answer (score 10):

From the command line we have to access to the `\updater` folder of `Notepad ++`

```
> cd /d C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\updater
```

then :

```
> gup -options
```

The window for proxy configuration is displayed:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what this answer adds to that by xs6 other than a screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

for 32 bit installation 
create a  file caleld gpupOptions.xml under updater folder where gpup.exe is present

file content

```
<GUPOptions>
    <Proxy>
        <server>proxy.com</server>
        <port>8080</port>
    </Proxy>
</GUPOptions>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set proxy for Plugin Manager, maybe you need to check this config file:
%AppData%\Notepad++\plugins\config\PluginManager.ini
There are proxy address and proxy port settings.

But in my personal experience, it's not working. Not sure what goes wrong.
I'm on Plugin Manager 1.4.9.0 with Notepad++ v7.5.6 (32-bit)